# Writing to application .plist file during building

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I have a framework distributed via CocoaPods. Can this framework write a key to the application `.plist` file during building? For example, add `NSCameraUsageDescription` row if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose, the main issue you will face is to find the exact location of the `plist` file in the folder. I've never done this, but in my project, I found info about location under the `/* Debug */` section (for example). Everything you have to do, is to add build phase with script in it. Script has to:

1. Find the location of the `plist`
2. Add the `NSCameraUsageDescription` to this `plist`

Technically, there are no obstacles